# Is it possible to add attributes to a property of dynamic object runtime?

Tags: c#, dynamic, expandoobject

I want to add an attribute to property of a dynamic object/expando object runtime, is it possible?

What I would like to do is:

```
dynamic myExpando = new ExpandoObject();
myExpando.SomeProp = "string";
myExpando.AddAttribute("SomeProp", new MyAttribute());
```

Is it possible to do that in one way or another?

Comment: why don't you run that code and see?

Comment: Have you checked out `TypeDescriptor`?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @SamIam: I don't think he expects it to work, but to be explicit, no.  It does not work.  The result is this: `RuntimeBinderException: 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for 'AddAttribute'`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563548/chow-to-add-a-attributes-to-an-object-at-runtime might also help

Comment: @user2720372:  Not a duplicate.  That doesn't help with attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an attribute to a dynamic object like this:

```
 dynamic myExpando = new ExpandoObject();
            myExpando.SomeProp = "string";
            TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(myExpando, new SerializableAttribute());
```

To read the attributes you should use this:

```
 dynamic values = TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(myExpando);
            for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(values[i]);
            }
```

I am not sure you can read custom attributes like that. However you can also try reflection:

```
 System.Reflection.MemberInfo info = myExpando.GetType();
            object[] attributes = info.GetCustomAttributes(true);
            for (int i = 0; i < attributes.Length; i++)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(attributes[i]);
            }
```

However, with reflection you cannot see the attribute that you have been added because attributes are static metadata.

TypeDescriptor is a metadata engine provided by the .NET FCL. You can read the article here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/parthopdas/archive/2006/01/03/509103.aspx

Comment: But this is adding the property to the type and not to the property.