# Error in serializing an object

Tags: c#, serialization, enterprise-library

I get the following error while Serializing an object.

Type 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Sql.SqlDatabase' in Assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is not marked as serializable.

Usual fix is to add [Serializable] to the error class.

As we dont have an editable class for SqlDatabase, does this mean I cant serialize it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an attribute at runtime: [C#: How to add an attributes to an object at run-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563548/chow-to-add-a-attributes-to-an-object-at-runtime)

```
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(type, attribs);
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(instance, attribs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to serialize the full object hierarchy? If not you can add the [XmlIgnore] attribute to properties that you don't want to serialize.

```
[XmlIgnore]
public TypeToIgnore PropertyToIgnore {
    get { return _propertyToIgnore; }
    set { _propertyToIgnore= value; }
}
```